# ZF2 - Control/customise individual radio/checkboxes

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm attempting to add `data-` values on radio buttons within ZF2. Is it possible to control each of the inputs specified with `value_options`?

A typical radio button added to a form:

```
$this->add(array(
    'type'  => 'radio',
    'name'  => 'duration',
    'options' => array(
        'value_options' => array(
            'daily' => 'Daily',
            'weekly' => 'Weekly',
            'monthly' => 'Monthly',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Ultimately, I would like something like the following, so I can specify individual parameters/options for each radio item:

```
$this->add(array(
    'type'  => 'radio',
    'name'  => 'duration',
    'options' => array(
        'value_options' => array(
            array(
                'attributes' => array(
                    'value' => 'daily',
                    'data-item' => 'apple'
                ),
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Daily'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'attributes' => array(
                    'value' => 'weekly',
                    'data-item' => 'orange'
                ),
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Weekly'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'attributes' => array(
                    'value' => 'monthly',
                    'data-item' => 'pear'
                ),
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Monthly'
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

My reason for wanting the above, is that I want to use JavaScript to change something upon selecting a radio button, so it needs to hold data attributes.

Is anything like this possible yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done by providing an array (or an object which implements ArrayAccess) instead of a single value (almost as you wrote in your example).

```
$this->add(array(
    'type'  => 'radio',
    'name'  => 'duration',
    'options' => array(
        'value_options' => array(
            'daily' => array(
                'label' => 'Daily',
                'value' => 'daily',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'data-item' => 'apple',
                ),
            ),
            'weekly' => array(
                'label' => 'Weekly',
                'value' => 'weekly',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'data-item' => 'orange',
                ),
            ),
            'monthly' => array(
                'label' => 'Monthly',
                'value' => 'monthly',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'data-item' => 'pear',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormMultiCheckbox.php#L177

This should work on radios, multi-checkboxes & selects too.